# Why am I being redirected when I launch Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I launch Jupyter with `jupyter-notebook` I get a redirect screen with the contents

> This page should redirect to Jupyter Notebook. If it doesn't, click here to go to Jupyter.

I am then redirected to the Jupyter home screen that I expected to land on in the first place. After that everything seems to work fine.

Why am I being redirected when I launch Jupyter? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The page redirection is because of the recent security update to Jupyter notebook in merged pull request [`#4260`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4260): *Launch the browser with a redirect file*. From now on, the Jupyter will open the file, which will redirect to the browser thus passing the token without putting it in a command-line argument, which may be visible to other users otherwise.

> This avoids putting the authentication token into a command-line argument to launch the browser, where it's visible to other users. Filesystem permissions should ensure that only the user who started the notebook can use this route to authenticate.

The new file included in PR is [`notebook/templates/browser-open.html`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/commit/51dae23b593ce74c0c99a9f13f2282e5c4c77da3#diff-f68f5eab41b9092b5b739944f53d5730R1):

```
{# This template is not served, but written as a file to open in the browser,
    passing the token without putting it in a command-line argument. #}
```